# How to Return an Error Message to ImportData()

Tags: rest, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm building a REST API, which is used mostly from Google Sheets at this point.

In Google Sheets I call my API using =ImportData(). I would like to return error messages that could be handled by =IFERROR() calls in Google Sheets, but I can't find any documentation / suggestions on how to do that.

I can return a string such as "#N/A - bad date in REST call", but IFERROR() would not know that this string is actually an error string.

Thanks!
Xavier

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=IF(A15="#N/A - bad date in REST call", ISNA(), A15)
```

where A15 is your `IMPORTDATA()`

[image]

Comment: I get that, but I'm looking for a "native" way to do this (without having to go through an intermediate layer of strings). Surely there must be a JSON object I can return that google sheet will interpret natively as an error that's been thrown (and show my error message when hovering over the cell that has returned the error).